# Go to new view on AJAX success using ActionResult

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AJAX call that posts data to the server to save to the DB. When this is complete, I want to call another ActionResult in the success callback to switch the user to a brand new view. This needs no data passed to it, I just need the success in the Ajax to call this method. Is this possible? I played with some of the URL helpers but I can seem to make this work, it just does nothing.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'Mapping/',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    data
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(result) {
                    if (result.success === true) {
                        alert('Yes');
                    } else {
                        alert('No');
                    }
                },
                failure: function() {
                    alert('No');
                }
```

So this would be in the first part of the success callback where it is currently set at aler('Yes').

Comment: Just redirect to your route in the success block.

Comment: So would this be the proper way to do it?  if (result.success === true) {
                        window.location.href = 'Success/';
                    }

Comment: can you share the result of your POST?

Comment: The result is just a simple Pass/Fail JSON object from the ActionResult method. return Json(new { success = true });

Comment: use "result.success == true" since your result will be a string "true". Other than that you should be good

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Ajax calls never redirect to another view. You can use `window.location.href = ...` to go to another view, but that would be pointless. If you want to redirect, use a normal form submit and redirect in the POST method (or return the view if there is an error) and remove the script.

Comment: What I am doing is creating a list of items with a clickable link on each one. when the user clicks the link I need to post data that is associated with that link, and then I change pages after that telling the user the data was submitted properly. I suppose I could overlay the page with a partial view.

Comment: @Rex, if you want to add an answer as to your comments I will accept the answer.

Comment: @mameesh added answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'Mapping/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                data
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success === 'true') {
                    window.location.href = 'Success/';
                } else {
                      //handle the failure from the response         
                }
            },
            failure: function() {
                //handle the failure of the request itself
            }
```